# Select Option for a Long list

Tags: html

I have a very long list of items and need to convert it into Select Option.  If I write 1 item at a time, it will take me a long time!

I am wondering if there are some ways to quickly convert a long list into Select Option.  Please help.

Thank you!

```
item1
item2
item3
....
itemxx
```

Convert to:

```
<select name="options">
      <option value="1">item1</option>
      <option value="2">item2</option>
      <option value="3">item3</option>
      ...............................
      <option value="xx">itemxx</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the deal with the list? Is it <li>, can you get it in array easily?

Comment: You need to get a good text editor with pattern matching search and replace. Or write a short Perl (or whatever) script.

Comment: It is a normal list, it is not a <li> list.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the features of [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).
You can use it to edit multiple lines at the same time. If you spend a lot of time with tasks like this, you will love it.

Of course there are other editors and other ways (like scripting or generating the elements with javascript) but we can just guess what skills you might have, or how often you'll have to do this.